# Branch name in SonarQube iOS project scanning using Fastlane

Tags: ios, sonarqube, fastlane

I am using Fastlane Action [sonar](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/sonar/) to scan my iOS projects. But I can't pass [sonar.branch.name](https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=11640256) in the action. I checked the [code](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/sonar.rb) on github but didn't found any support for branch name there. So is there an alternate solution to this? 
Final solution is to ditch fastlane is write a script to execute sonar scan.

Comment: If this is a common enough use case you could also just create an issue for fastlane or - even better - create a Pull Request adding the feature yourself. (Ruby is pretty "simple" to get if you know any other modern language, and the fastlane repo is happy to accept contributions and help you get them merged.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added this functionality in fastlane and now it's possible via branch_name property. 
Released in version **2.121.0**
https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/releases/tag/2.121.0